How to get from polars data frame to xgboost training without memory duplicates?
I am toying with polars for manipulating data in Python. Then I want to train an xgboost model. The Dmatrix format doesn't seem to handle polars DataFrame natively.
What would be the best way to train on polars DataFrame while avoiding unnecessary memory copies ? go trough numpy ?

As far as I know, XGBoost does take (Arrow backed) dataframes, but it may not be supporting all data types. This was introduced in 2.1.0, see the entry "Now supports dataframe data format in native XGBoost." (https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changes/v2.1.0.html#features) So if you are on an older version of XGBoost, it may be worth updating to give that a shot first.
